# Create array, grouping based on child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, casperjs

I have this html:

```
<select id="this_id">
 <option value="0" class="empty-item">Choose Type</option>
 <optgroup label="FirstGrouping"></optgroup>
 <option value="2">Thing1</option>
 <optgroup label="SecondGrouping"></optgroup>
 <option value="8">Thing4</option>
 <option value="4">Thing3</option>
 <optgroup label="ThirdGrouping"></optgroup>
 <option value="7">Thing8</option>
 <option value="5">Thing9</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to do is to create an array that would look like this:

```
"data": [{
    "Label": "FirstGrouping",
    "Options": ["Thing1"]
}, {
    "Label": "SecondGrouping",
    "Options": ["Thing4", "Thing3"]
}, {
    "Label": "ThirdGrouping",
    "Options": ["Thing8", "Thing9"]
}]
```

There is no given ordering of `optgroup` and `option` elements. So basically I need to group first `optgroup` and the following `options` elements in first object inside `data` array. Where `"Label"` is `optgroup` and `"Options"` are all the `option` elements before the next following `optgroup` element. Second object inside `data` has next `optgroup` as its `"Label"` and `"Options"` are the following `option` elements before the following `optgroup` element. And so on.

If `optgroup` **would wrap** `option` elements, then I could do something like:

```
var yearz = [];
var yearz2 = $('#this_id');
yearz2.each(function() {
    var thelabel = $(this).attr('label');
    var lengthch = $(this).children().length;
    var thisch = $(this).children();
    var theobj = [];
    var alls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lengthch; i++) {
        alls.push({
            "Value": thisch.eq(i).val(),
            "Text": thisch.eq(i).text()
        });
    }
    theobj = {
        Label: thelabel.trim(),
        Options: alls
    };

    yearz.push(theobj);
});
```

**But ´optgroup´ does not wrap `option` elements.** 
Is there any clever way to do it?
Best Regards

Comment: Do you have the HTML in a string or in the current page/document?

Comment: @trincot Current page/document, `casperjs`

Comment: Aren't the `optgroup`s supposed to wrap their `option`s?

Comment: @connexo In this case it actually does not.

Comment: Any code that you experimented with? Or anything that prevents you from starting?

Comment: @sabithpocker Yes, I tried some stuff but did not suceed. I know how to check with `.is()`, if it is `optgroup` or `option` but can sucess grouping it...

Comment: @sabithpocker Please see my edit, if `optgroup` would wrap `option` elements. But it does not in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this ES5 code:

```js
var data = [];
var elems = document.getElementById('this_id').children;
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    var el = elems[i];
    if (el.tagName === 'OPTGROUP') {
        data.push({ label: el.getAttribute('label'), options: []});
    } else if(el.tagName === 'OPTION' && data.length) {
        data[data.length-1].options.push(el.textContent);
    }
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<select id="this_id">
 <optgroup label="FirstGrouping"></optgroup>
 <option value="2" style="text-indent: 10px;">Thing1</option>
 <optgroup label="SecondGrouping"></optgroup>
 <option value="8" style="text-indent: 10px;">Thing4</option>
 <option value="4" style="text-indent: 10px;">Thing3</option>
 <optgroup label="ThirdGrouping"></optgroup>
 <option value="7" style="text-indent: 10px;">Thing8</option>
 <option value="5" style="text-indent: 10px;">Thing9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this es6 solution?

Comment: Yes, it is. you need ES5?

Comment: Now it is ES5 compliant.

Comment: Thanks, but does not seem to work. Maybe something with the first `empty` option, that one needs to skip? The `option` before the first `optgroup`. Sorry seems like update did not add that option previosly...

Comment: Right now it says `VM5207:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined(…)`

Comment: Ah yes `for (var i=1; i<elems.length; i++) {` works. Please update and I accept. Thanks a lot

Comment: I replaced `querySelectorAll`, as it might not be supported in capserjs either (that is an ES6 feature). I added an extra condition, in case you have `OPTION` tags occurring before any `OPTGROUP` tags. That is more generic as a solution than putting `i=1`.